# Evaluating constants of an inverse estimate

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, estimation, functional-inequalities

In some analysis on a domain $\Gamma$, I want to employ a type of inverse estimate
$$\|F\|_X \le \frac{k}{\Delta{x}}\|F\|_{L^2(\Gamma)}$$
where $F$ belongs to a finite-dimensional subspace, $\|X\|$ is equivalent to $H^1(\Gamma)$ (i.e. $\|F\|^2_X \le c\|F\|^2_{H^1(\Gamma)}$ for some constant $c$), $k$ is a constant of the inverse estimate, and $\Delta{x}$ is a known value: the size of a computational mesh.

- How can I go about estimating possible values of the constant of inverse inequality  $k$?
- Is it possible to ensure the inverse inequality is realistic and useful in practice, without estimating $k$?

Comment: What is $\Delta x$? What is $k$?

Comment: @HansEngler Thanks, I have added some clarification.

Comment: This is only possible if $F$ belongs to some finite-dimensional subspace.

Comment: @daw Yes, F definitely belongs to a finite-dimensional subspace!